# Style the popup list of an AutoCompleteTextField

Tags: codenameone

The following code doesn't work to style the items of a popup of an AutoCompleteTextField. What is the fix?

Java:

```
    Form hi = new Form("CSS Test", BoxLayout.y());
    AutoCompleteTextField ac = new AutoCompleteTextField("Short", "Shock", "Sholder", "Shrek");
    ac.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);
    hi.add(ac);
    hi.show();
```

CSS:

```
AutoCompleteList {
    font-size: 2.5mm;
    font-family: "native:MainLight";
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

AutoCompleteList.pressed, AutoCompleteList.selected {
    color: blue;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-auto-complete-renderer.html you need to style the UIID of the reneder not of the list. Try `ListRenderer` and `ListRendererFocus` UIID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just find a possible solution:

Java

```
    Form hi = new Form("CSS Test", BoxLayout.y());
    AutoCompleteTextField ac = new AutoCompleteTextField("Short", "Shock", "Sholder", "Shrek");
    ac.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);
    ac.setCompletionRenderer(getCompletionRenderer());
    hi.add(ac);
    hi.show();
```

and

```
private ListCellRenderer getCompletionRenderer() {
    DefaultListCellRenderer render = new DefaultListCellRenderer(false);
    render.setUIID("MyAutoCompleteList");
    return render;
}
```

CSS:

```
MyAutoCompleteList {
    font-size: 2.5mm;
    font-family: "native:MainLight";
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3mm;
    border: 1pt black solid;
}

MyAutoCompleteList.pressed, MyAutoCompleteList.selected {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: blue;
}
```